# How to deduce template by struct's member

Tags: c++, templates

Suppose I have some structs and each of them holds one enum as a member. 
I want to call a method of a struct but depending on a struct's member, like in the code example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits> 

enum class Type{
    lowercase = 0,
    uppercase
};

struct Low{
    static constexpr Type cp = Type::lowercase;
};

struct Up{
    static constexpr Type cp = Type::uppercase;
};


template<typename Case, typename=void>
struct Printer
{
    void print_g(const std::string& s){
        std::cout << "just s: " << s << std::endl;
    }
};

template<typename X>
struct Printer<X, std::enable_if_t<X::cp == Type::lowercase, void>>
{
    void print_g(const std::string& s){
        std::cout << "lowercase " << std::nouppercase << s << std::endl;
    }
};

template<typename X>
struct Printer <X, std::enable_if_t<X::cp == Type::uppercase, void>>
{
    void print_g(const std::string& s){
        std::cout << "uppercase " << std::uppercase << s << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Printer<Low> pl;
    pl.print_g("hello1");
    Printer<Up> p2;
    p2.print_g("hello2");
}
```

But this solution doesn't look quite elegant to me. 
Especially the part **typname=void** in the first template. 
Only then code compiles. Why is that the case?
And is there any better (more elegant) solution for this template specialization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++17, you can use `if constexpr`:

```
template <typename X>
struct Printer
{
    void print_g(const std::string& s)
    {
        if constexpr(X::cp == Type::lowercase)
        {
            std::cout << "lowercase " << std::nouppercase << s << std::endl;
        }
        else if constexpr(X::cp == Type::uppercase)
        {
            std::cout << "uppercase " << std::uppercase << s << std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "just s: " << s << std::endl;
        }
    }
};
```

If you do not have access to C++17, consider these options:

- Use a regular `if`...`else` statement. There's no code that needs to be conditionally compiled in your example.
- Implement `static_if` in C++14. Here's a talk I gave that explains how to do it: [Implementing `static` control flow in C++14](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aXSsUqVSe2k)

Comment: Nice :) Thanks a lot!

Comment: And is there C++14 way of doing that?
Since I'm kind of limited with compiler version.

Comment: @anicicn: in your particular case, you can use a regular `if` statement.

Answer (score 1):

You can [fully specialize](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization) `Printer` for `Low` and `Up`.

```
template<class Case>
struct Printer
{
    void print_g(const std::string& s) {
        std::cout << "just s: " << s << std::endl;
    }
};

template<>
struct Printer<Low>
{
    void print_g(const std::string& s) {
        std::cout << "lowercase " << std::nouppercase << s << std::endl;
    }
};

template<>
struct Printer<Up>
{
    void print_g(const std::string& s) {
        std::cout << "uppercase " << std::uppercase << s << std::endl;
    }
};
```

Notice that the enum does not come into play at all. If you need to specialize for the enum, you can do that too.

```
template<Type Case>
struct PrinterHelper
{
    void print_g(const std::string& s) {
        std::cout << "just s: " << s << std::endl;
    }
};

template<>
struct PrinterHelper<Type::lowercase>
{
    void print_g(const std::string& s) {
        std::cout << "lowercase " << std::nouppercase << s << std::endl;
    }
};

template<>
struct PrinterHelper<Type::uppercase>
{
    void print_g(const std::string& s) {
        std::cout << "uppercase " << std::uppercase << s << std::endl;
    }
};

template<class Case>
using Printer = PrinterHelper<Case::cp>;
```

Answer (score 1):

I would likely just go with:

```
enum struct Casing
{
    Lower,
        Upper
};
template<Casing>
struct printer;
template<>
struct printer<Casing::Lower>
{
    ...
};
template<>
struct printer<Casing::Upper>
{
...
};
```